# Hibernate. In CustomType what are registration keys for?

Tags: java, hibernate

Hi there can anyone explain to me how the CustomType field 'String[] registrationKeys' are used?

In all the documentation although Ive come across, explanations about CustomType and examples, I havent come across any application of it.

Answer (score 1):

This is the contract for the registration keys:

```
/**
 * Get the names under which this type should be registered in the type registry.
 *
 * @return The keys under which to register this type.
 */
public String[] getRegistrationKeys();
```

And for example, the org.hibernate.type.TimestampType is a good example of what the registration keys look like:

```
public String getName() {
    return "timestamp";
}

@Override
public String[] getRegistrationKeys() {
    return new String[] { getName(), Timestamp.class.getName(), java.util.Date.class.getName() };
}
```

So the timestampType will be made available under all three keys:

- timestamp
- java.sql.Timestamp
- java.util.Date

And the type resolver will use these keys to fetch the right Java-to-SQL Type converter.